# jquery attr value returns undefined or 0 if value is a large number

Tags: jquery, attr

First of all I am sorry if such problem has been asked because I have been searching for many many hours. Please bear with my problem. Let me elaborate. I am dynamically adding options to a select element with "value" attribute as simple 10 digit phone number like 7465768574 & text as "Name(PhoneNumber)" which when user chooses, is added to an unordered list to show Users selected option. To remove that list item I have provided an image which on clicking first checks that there is a corresponding option in the select element & then removes the same list item from the unordered list & removes the corresponding option from the select element. NOW, to accomplish this I am checking the 'value' attribute. Problem is that if that value attribute is big number like a phone number, my logic fails because jQuery cant extract that value properly. if its a really big number it returns 0, if its something in range of 6,000,000,000 to 7,000,000,000 ( comma isnt there in value ) it returns some random number. I dont know what the problem is. Is it something to do with type of value or something.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="select1">  
     <option class="selectedoptions" value="8234567890">Joker(8234567890)</option>  
     <option class="selectedoptions" value="2">Batman(2)</option>  
     <option class="selectedoptions" value="3">Superman(3)</option>  
     <option class="selectedoptions" value="4">Spiderman(4)</option>
     <option class="selectedoptions" value="5">Ironman(5)</option> 
     <option class="selectedoptions" value="6">Thor(6)</option> 
     <option class="selectedoptions" value="7">Loki(7)</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery code is

```
        function removeSelected() {
            var check = $(this).parent().attr('value');
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $('#select2 option').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('value') == check) {
                    $(this).remove().appendTo('#select1');
                    parent.remove();
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            });
            return true;
        }
```

When I debug this code with FireBug, I can see that for larger numbers , "check" is 0, & for some range lesser than 8,000,000,000 its returning random numbers. For smaller numbers its working perfectly.

Also if I try .val() instead of .attr('value') firebug show error

```
TypeError: (c.value || "").replace is not a function
```

Thanks in advance guys.

EDIT 1: Okay. It seems my jQuery code which is dynamically adding the List Item is introducing random number as value in the list Item. But the problem remains same.. I can see my code ( through firebug) adding proper value while creating List Item but the generated List Item does not reflect it.

EDIT 2: In response to Mr. ronalchn. I am sorry. a context is needed. What I have are following. 2 select elements "select1" & "select2" & an unordered list "selectedlist". Users can choose options from "select1" & move it to "select2". & "select2" options will/should reflect as list items of "selectedlist". I have a function removeSelected bound to an image inside the list item.

```
<li class="selectedlistItems" value="8123456789">
Joker(8123456789)
<a class="search-choice-close" href="#"> </a>
</li>
```

Now in function I am trying to iterate through the options of "select2" & check which of its options have the same value as this list item has. "check" is list item's "value" &

```
$(this).attr('value')
```

is "select2 option" value. 
if it matches then

```
$(this).remove().appendTo('#select1');
```

removes the "select2 option" & appends it to "select1"
where as

```
parent.remove();
```

removes the list item, so that the unordered list always reflects the "select2" element.

I guess this context will be good enough to understand what I am trying to do. I am new to jquery & generally I post questions, I just find answer , this is my first question ever. I am already thankful for such fast response.

EDIT 3 : Check this jsFiddle to understand the situation. http://jsfiddle.net/ygaurav/vUgym/

Comment: I can't replicate this in Firefox 12 on OSX.

Comment: [`.attr()` and `.val()` works just fine with large values](http://jsfiddle.net/mdWfJ/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, when you are assigning it to the `'value'` property of the `<li>` element, this `'value'` is of a `'number'` type. Which is why it causes overflow and you get a garbage value back.

Why not to use custom attribute, what I mean by that is instead of `'value'` use some other custom attribute. Ex. say `'toonId'`

```
$('#list').append($("<li></li>").html(Joker(8123456789)'<a class=search-choice-close href=#></a>').attr('toonId', "8234567890"));
```

When rendered this is how it will look :

```
<li class="selectedlistItems" toonId="8234567890">Joker(8123456789)<a class="search-choice-close" href="#"> </a></li>
```

This will add a new attribute to the `<li>` item and you can access the `'toonId'` property later wherever you want.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a TON !! I knew it had to be about value as integer/number, but I couldn't make it work somehow. this solves 2 things actually, giving custom attribute which is more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` definitely works with large numbers, because it just returns a string.

I tried your code on jsfiddle. Of course, it was missing a few details, so I just creatively added it. Then I fixed some of your code which didn't seem correct. Anyways, it is working now.

http://jsfiddle.net/QA5nk/1/

The changes include the following lines:

```
var check = $(this).attr('value'); // instead of looking for the parent
...
// parent.remove(); // this line is removing what is already removed
```

You tried removing something twice, which also made the page blow up, so I commented that out.

Comment: I think a little context was necessary to what I am trying to do. I have edited my question. But I already thank you for such fast response sir.

Comment: No it is not clear. You don't even have a `select2` HTML element. So it is still very unclear what you want. Try put your code into a jsfiddle, so that you give a better idea of all the HTML elements that exist.

Comment: Here the situation . If you use it. You can see that options with 2,3 is working but not for batman with larger number as value.
You can double click on options in select1 to move them to select 2 then click apply to reflect changes to selected list. Click on the right corner of list items ( image is empty but you can hover to see the anchor inside them)
http://jsfiddle.net/ygaurav/vUgym/

Comment: I tried this in both Chrome and Firefox, and everything appears to work correctly...

Comment: It's working for you ?? I cant seem to be able to remove Joker(823456789). I wish i could show you a video. :-( My first question on stackoverflow & no one seems to be able to replicate the problem. Thanks anyway for your time sir. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yep, I am able to add and remove Joker, I also tested apply and stuff, and found no problems.